# How to Deserialize XMLDocument to object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, xml-deserialization

I have a .Net webserivce that accepts `XML` in string format. `XML` String sent into the webserivce can represent any Object in the system. I need to check the first node to figure out what object to deserialize the XML string. For this I will have to load the XML into an `XMLDocument` (Don't want to use RegEx or string compare). I am wondering if there is a way to Deserialize the `XMLDocument/XMLNode` rather that deserializing the string to save some performance? Is there going to be any performance benefit serializing the `XMLNode` rather that the string?

Method to Load XMLDocument

```
public void LoadFromString(String s)
{
    m_XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    m_XmlDoc.LoadXml(s);        
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have an `XmlDocument`, you can use `XmlNodeReader` as an `XmlReader` to pass to `XmlSerializer`, but I wonder if it would be better to do it the other way; use an `XmlReader` to get the outermost element name, and give *that* to `XmlSerializer`...

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<foo id='123'/>";
        object obj;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "foo":
                    obj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo)).Deserialize(reader);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Unexpected: " + reader.Name);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, finally a question I could answer with my eyes shut, you beat me to it :).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget a powerfull contender, LINQ to XML!

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(myfile);

var foos = root.Descendants("Foo").Where(e => e.Attribute("bar") != null);
```

Comment: Application I am working on is stuck on .Net 2.0. I wish that was not the case.

Comment: don't forget to add System.Xml.Linq to your program's references