# Shortest way to deserialize XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.5, .net-4.6

I am looking for a clean and short way to deserialize a `XmlDocument` object. The closest thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694860/how-to-deserialize-xmldocument-to-object-in-c) but I am really wondering if there is no nicer way to do this (in .NET 4.5 or even 4.6) since I already have the XmlDocument.

So currently this looks as follows:

```
// aciResponse.Data is a XmlDocument
MyClass response;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create((new StringReader(aciResponse.Data.InnerXml))))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    response =  (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Thanks for any better idea!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are thinking might constitute a `nicer` / `cleaner` way?

Comment: well, something that maybe does not involve to create/open two different readers and using the InnerXml (string)?

Comment: This is what methods and extension methods are for, if you're doing a lot of the same code, extract to a function... That code looks pretty concise to me; so probably be more specific.

Comment: Maybe there really is no "nicer" solution - but that's what I like to find out here ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could forgo the `XmlReader` and use a [`TextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and use the `TextReader` [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Working example:

```
void Main()
{
   String aciResponseData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><tag><bar>test</bar></tag>";
   using(TextReader sr = new StringReader(aciResponseData))
   {
        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        MyClass response =  (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        Console.WriteLine(response.bar);
   }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("tag")]
public class MyClass
{
   public String bar;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's at least a bit shorter solution :) I'll wait, however, if there might be more suggestions.

Answer (score 23):

If you already have a `XmlDocument` object than you could use [`XmlNodeReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

```
MyClass response = null;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(aciResponse.Data))
{
    response = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: In my case, I found XmlNodeReader ~5 times faster than using XmlReader + StringReader

Answer (score 13):

There is a better and lazy way to do this. But it is possible only if you are using Visual Studio.

Steps:

1. Open Visual Studio and create a new class file (say Sample1.cs). Now
   remove the sample class definition from this class file.
2. Copy your XML file into the clipboard (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C)
3. In Visual Studio, go to Edit menu and select "Paste Special"->"Paste XML as Classes".

Done. Visual Studio will generate all the class definitions required to de-serialize this XML.